# Access 97 ODBC call failure String data, right truncation

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am building a web front end for a ms sql database.  The goal is to move away from access 97.  Basically, I can insert data into the data base from the web front end.  I can view the database table where the records are being inserted within Access 97.  The web front end writes, updates, and deleted records in the database just fine.

The problem is that i get ODBC call failure String data, right truncation error in Access 97 only when I try to edit rows in Access that were added from the web front end.  The error also occurs when I try to edit records in Access 97 that were added directly to the ms sql database via an sql statement.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with the data that is being inserted into the ms sql database.  I have no idea how Access works.  I tried running a profile to view SQL transactions between Access and the ms sql db but I could not figure out why the access updates are failing.

How are Access row updates different than direct updates to the ms sql database that the Access application is using?

**EDIT: I solved the issue.** There was a column in the table that was of type Binary length 50. This is a column that is not really used so every time i insert I inserted 0 for this column.  After changing this insert value of null it fixed the issue.  Access couldn't handle a binary values of length 50

Comment: When you say "when I try to edit rows in Access", how are you accessing the data? Is this through a linked table and you have the table data opened directly, or is it being displayed on an Access form?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by linked table, but I open the table in Access. I am not editing the rows in a form.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ODBC connection string that Access is using to to connect to the MS SQL database:

[image]

If this is checked then the driver converts numbers into the local regional format which could include a thousands indicater (eg 1,000 instead of 1000).  This increases the length of the returned data and can blow the buffers used.

To fix, ensure the option is not ticked.

Comment: That didn't work.  That is unchecked in all that ODBC configurations.  Also i am using ms sql 2000 and access 97, not sql server 2008